# Meanvalue theorem for quadratic arguments

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives

I have trouble proving the following result and I would be happy about any kind of suggestion how the precise argument looks like.

Let $f : [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote a continuously differentiable and globally Lipschitz-continuous function. Then there exists a constant C such that
$$
\left|\frac{f(v^2)-f(w^2)}{v^2-w^2} - f^{\prime}\left(\left(\frac{v+w}{2}\right)^2\right) \right| \le C |v-w|^2
$$
for all $v,w\in\mathbb{R}$.

The proof seems to be based on the meanvalue theorem. Has anyone seen this estimate before?

Thanks a lot in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: I don't think it's true. If we choose $f(x) = e^x$, and $v,w = x+1,x$, we get
$$
\left(\frac{e^{x^2+2x+1} - e^{x^2}}{2x+1} - e^{x^2+x+1/2}\right)/(1)^2 \to \infty 
$$
So it can't be bounded by any constant $C$

Comment: Hi Farnight! Thanks for your answer!!Unfortunately, I forgot that f is supposed to be Lipschitz-continuous. Sorry for that!!